# SQLite doesn't create database tables, crashes irc bot

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

So, when I connected, or attempt, it runs this code in Database.cs. 
Also, I'm using SmartIRC4Net for IRC handling
Now I know this is the error because Init() in Database.cs doesn't even run! If it is, it doesn't create the "trubot.sqlite" file with the tables.

I have no idea why it's doing it, but it is.

Here's the Database.cs code:

```
    public void Init(){
        try {
            if (File.Exists("trubot.sqlite")) {
                dbf = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=trubot.sqlite;Version=3");
                dbf.Open();
                String db;
                db = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '"+chan+"' (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user TEXT, currency INTEGER DEFAULT 0, subscriber INTEGER DEFAULT 0, battletag TEXT DEFAULT null, uLevel INTEGER DEFAULT 0, mod INTEGER DEFAULT 0, rlvl INTEGER DEFAULT 0);";
                using (query = new SQLiteCommand(db, dbf)){
                    query.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            } else {
                 SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("trubot.sqlite");
                 dbf = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=trubot.sqlite;Version=3");
                 dbf.Open();
                 String db;
                 db = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '"+chan+"' (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user TEXT, currency INTEGER DEFAULT 0, subscriber INTEGER DEFAULT 0, battletag TEXT DEFAULT null, uLevel INTEGER DEFAULT 0, mod INTEGER DEFAULT 0, rlvl INTEGER DEFAULT 0);";
                 using (query = new SQLiteCommand(db, dbf)){
                    query.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception s) {
            Console.WriteLine("[ERROR] Error in code. " + s.Message);
        }
    }
    public void addUser(String user) {
       // add new user
        try {
            if (!usrExist(user)) {
               String db = "INSERT INTO '"+chan+"' (user) VALUES ('"+user+"');";
               using (query = new SQLiteCommand(db,dbf)) {
                    query.ExecuteNonQuery();
               }
            }
       } catch (Exception err) {
               Console.WriteLine("addUser is causing an error: " + err.Message);
           }
    }
```

and here's the other reason it crashes (which is in Program.cs)

```
public static void OnJoined(object sender, JoinEventArgs e) {
    try {
        var conf = new Config();
        var db = new Database();
        Console.WriteLine("[SELF] ["+conf.Channel+"] > *** "+e.Data.Nick+" has joined the channel!");
        if (!db.usrExist(e.Data.Nick)) {
            try {
                db.addUser(e.Data.Nick);
            } catch (Exception er1) {
               string lnNum = er1.StackTrace.Substring(er1.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7);
               Console.WriteLine("Error: -- Trubot Error "+ er1.Message + " " + er1.Data.ToString()
                          + " " + er1.InnerException.Message.ToString()
                          + " " + er1.TargetSite.ToString() + " Ln: " + lnNum);
               Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception er1) {
         string lnNum = er1.StackTrace.Substring(er1.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7);
         Console.WriteLine("Error: -- Trubot Error "+ er1.Message + " " + er1.Data.ToString()
               + " " + er1.InnerException.Message.ToString()
               + " " + er1.TargetSite.ToString() + " Ln: " + lnNum);
         Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Side note: I'd use MySQL but I need this application to be as portable as possible and run on as many operating systems as possible. I'd rather use SQLite than MSSQL or MySQL.

Comment: You never told us what exactly is the error. From a complete stab in the dark, my guess is file permissions are blocking creating the sqlite data file or blocking the modification of the data file.

Comment: The error was it'd would just cease connection, saying that it's missing variables from the SmartIRC4Net::Connect() void.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was when I assigned the channel to the SQL as a Table Name, I needed to remove the "#" from it. So here's the resulting code:

```
public Database() {
    var conf = new Config();
    chan = conf.Channel.Replace("#","");
    Init();
}
```

Comment: 1. You shouldn't dynamically create tables like that. Add the channel name as a column of a central table instead. 2. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Do you know what will happen if a user named `"); DROP TABLE some_channel; --` enters?

Comment: It's a Twitch IRC bot, there are limitations to what a username can be.